# node.js request.js Why is my IP address changing?

Tags: node.js, http, request

Just doing a simple GET request to whatismyip.org, and I get a different IP everytime. If it visit the website in my browser, it's always the same. What's up with this? I'm just running node.js locally on my windows 7 machine. How is it possible that I'm using different IPs?

```
request('http://www.whatsmyip.org/', function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        res.render('index', {content:body;});
    }
});
```

I feel like `http://www.whatsmyip.org` knows it's an automated request and is trolling me. xD

Comment: Is your browser configured to use a proxy? What happens if you try to hit the URL with cURL?

Comment: How different are the IP addresses you're seeing?

Comment: Really different, and you know what. I tried `http://whatismyipaddress.com` and it's my IP everytime. I think `http://www.whatsmyip.org` was actually trolling me... can anyone confirm this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the site is using JavaScript to update the span on the page, so if you're doing a simple HTTP request then that won't be updated to the correct value.  If you go to the site with a Web browser but just view the source (not using any updated inspector) and refresh then the IP displayed appears to be random.

Answer (score 2):

Read the HTML comment right above the IP address:

```
<!--
Please DO NOT program a bot to use this site to grab your IPs. It kills my server and thats not nice.
Just get some cheap or free web hosting and make your own IP-only page to power your bot.
Then you won't even have to parse any html, just load the IP directly - better for everyone!!
-->
```

Comment: It's cool, I'm not using any bots. Just doing a few requests to test something.